# Index out of bounds on NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is my Log...

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

i don't know what to do...
can anyone help me what is wrong?

Comment: you tried to access a character index in the string which does not exist.  Look at the stack trace it will tell you what line it occurred on.

Answer (score 3):

Each character in a string (e.g. `@"ABCD"` ) has an associated index. In my example, 'A' would be at index 0, 'B', at index 1, 'C' at index 2 etc.

A string's `length` (e.g. `NSUInteger stringLength = myStringInstance.length;` ) equals the total number of characters in the string. The string `@"ABCD"`has a length of 4.

The statement `NSString *mySubString = [@"ABCD" substringToIndex:2];` would make `mySubString` equal to `@"AB"`. You cannot try to access an index greater than or equal to the length of the string- e.g. `NSString *myOtherSubString = [@"ABCD" substringToIndex:4];` would crash.

Hope this helps.

Comment: NSString *myOtherSubString = [@"ABCD" substringToIndex:4];  doesnt crash. In this case it will return the copy.
This is from apple's documentation.
"A new string containing the characters of the receiver up to, but not including, the one at anIndex. If anIndex is equal to the length of the string, returns a copy of the receiver."

Answer (score 0):

This is probably diagnostic of some other problem.

You're probably mismanaging memory somewhere else in your program.

This can cause your string to be "replaced" by a different string.